# White space below TextView when setting text

Tags: android, android-layout

When I set a long text inside my AutoResizeTextView (id textearticlecomplet), the text is well inside the textview but below it, there is a long white space. However, the text doesn't contain this white space.

Where have I made a mistake ?

Here is the code of the layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EDE5E2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagedetailarticle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_picture" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleaticledetail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sourcedetailarticle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <com.rss.utils.AutoResizeTextView
            android:id="@+id/textearticlecomplet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:text="Chargement en cours ..."
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/articleoriginal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Consulter l&apos;article sur le web"
            android:textColor="@color/consulteroriginal"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove this from your (com.rss.utils.AutoResizeTextView)

```
android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes @Sagar seems to be correct. The only extra space appearing from your xml is the marginBottom. Remove that and it should do.